# Download XML client-side, fetch data from Session first

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

My goal is to have the user be able to download some information currently stored in Session. There are multiple key/value pairs in Session I would like to have the user download as one XML file.

The control I am working with has a client-side 'onClick' event exposed. I was planning on calling a PageMethod to extract the data I wanted from Session, and return that data to the client.

I've seen a very clean implementation of this in MVC and I am wondering if this clean implementation is possible in ASP.NET AJAX, as well. If not, I am wondering what the best route would be to go for this.

In MVC/JavaScript I see something like this:

```
location.href = "../WorkOrders/Export/" + workOrderID;

public ActionResult Export(int id)
{
    WorkOrderPdfExporter exporter = new WorkOrderPdfExporter();
    byte[] buffer = exporter.Export(id);
    return File(buffer, "application/pdf", String.Format("workorder#{0}.pdf", id));
}
```

This Export method returns a FileContentResult which is an MVC thing. I am wondering if something like this exists in ASP.NET AJAX, and if the datatype is suitable to return for a Page Method.

If not, what should I be doing here? I was thinking about creating a dictionary, sticking the relevant session objects into this dictionary, serializing it to XML (I have a Serializable Dictionary class implemented), ...and then attempting to return that XML for download?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the point of trying to use AJAX?

Comment: I am attempting to allow the user to create a file which is represenative of state. Then, later, load that file up to change the state back to what was saved. Sorry, I may have used the word AJAX too loosely?

The reasoning behind doing it client-side is that I am working with a RadSlidingPane control which does not have an 'OnClick' event-handler implicitly. It seemed cleaner to fetch the data from the server and download client-side rather than attempt to bind a server-side OnClick event handler to only this instance of RadSlidingPane.

Comment: Do you want the user to download the file? That's what the MVC code appears to do (prompt the user to save a pdf).

Comment: Well, there is no currently existing file. If I have to create the file on the server first, so be it, but ideally I would like to just pass the stream / string representation of the contents of the file, and have the file be created/downloaded using those contents + specified name/filetype.

Comment: As I said, the function should work almost unmodified in regular ASP.NET or MVC, whichever you use. The AJAX call should just point to the URL that will return the file (in memory or otherwise) to the browser.

Comment: The file returned in the code above comes from System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult which is not known to WebForms. I was curious if there was an equivalent class.

Comment: No, nothing as simple. You _could_ use `Response.OutputStream` and set the content-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write directly to [`HttpResponse.OutputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx) - you will need to set the correct [`ContentType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype.aspx) too.

The code example for `OutputStream` is rather verbose (mostly dealing with a dynamically created image), but if you ignore those parts, you will have a basic function that will need minor modification for your use.

Comment: PageMethods are required to be static. I am unable to access HttpResponse.OutputStream from a static method. Hmm.. this might've been said too quickly. One moment. I am going to try and use HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream and see if this gets me where I want. Thank you!

Comment: @Sean - Yeah, was about to suggest `HttpContext.Current` :)

Comment: Hi, are you still present? I've got an example together, but it does not trigger the download as expected.